# div inside .html() function of jquery for styling of content

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load the div content of one page with other content on click of a link.For that purpose I am using .click() function and .html() function which has all the content.This is working fine.
But now I want the contents to be styled.So I am using divs inside the html() function to do so.But it is not working.The content is not getting displayed at all.
The jQuery code is as follows..

```
$(".vision").click(function(){

    $("#rightcolumn").html("<div id="rightcol_h1">VISION</div>");
    });
```

rightcolumn is the div name that has to be changed. And rightcol_h1 is to style the heading.
It is as follows..

```
    #rightcol_h1{
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #00578C;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

When I do this nothing is getting displayed.What am I doing wrong.Is the way i have used div inside html() wrong?

Comment: Don't know it this is the problem, but did you debug the code via console? "<div id="rightcol_h1">VISION</div>" should be "<div id='rightcol_h1'>VISION</div>".

Comment: thank you.. Got it running by this. So whichever divs I have to use I have to put them in single quotes.Got it.

Comment: Actually, you dont need to use single quotes, it's important you don't "break" your string declaration. You could do any of these:
- "<div id='rightcol_h1'>VISION</div>"
- '<div id="rightcol_h1">VISION</div>'
- "<div id=\"rightcol_h1\">VISION</div>"

Answer (score 2):

You've messed up the quotes, but a better way to create elements would be :

```
$(".vision").on('click', function(){
    var rightCol = $('<div />', {id: 'rightcol_h1', text: 'VISION'});
    $("#rightcolumn").html(rightCol);
});
```

Comment: tried this one but still no change.The link does not work. Could you tell me how have I messed up the quotes?

Comment: @user2260603 - Do you have an element with the class .vision, what does the HTML of that element look like, is it dynamically inserted. Did you remember document ready etc.

Comment: Oh, and use jQuery 1.7 or above, preferably 2.0 now ?